# Using "It" in a Sentence

Tags: pronouns, it-its-itself

I have a question regarding using the word *it* in a sentence. My question is whether I am properly using the pronoun *it* in the text below:

> Making mistakes is an expected part of life; it is inevitable.

Thank you for your time. Any feedback is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are.  The pronoun "it" clearly refers back to the antecedent "making mistakes."

Comment: Thanks for the information, Billy! That answer was exactly what I was looking for :). I guess I was wondering if I could use "it" to refer to "making mistakes."

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me. I'm not sure what else it could be.

> "Making mistakes **is** an inevitable part of life; **it** is inevitable."
>   "Do you mean that mistakes **are** inevitable? Shouldn't you have said that **they** are inevitable?"
>   "No, I wasn't referring to the mistakes themselves. I was referring to the act of ***making*** *mistakes*. That's also why I said **is** at first."

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Thinking about it more, I can see that I was wondering if I could use "it" to refer to "making mistakes."

Comment: I appreciate the timely feedback.